# jax-rs map query parameter object

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using jersey 1.2 with jersey-server, jersey-json and jersey-spring to create REST services.

One of my service

```java
@Path("test")
public class TestViewRestController {

@GET
@Path("t1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public RetPojo getPojo(
        @QueryParam("token") @DefaultValue("null") String token, 
        @QueryParam("pojo") ParamPojo pojo, 
        @QueryParam("param2") @DefaultValue("null") String param2
        ) {
       //do some stuff
}

}
```

I've created a Provider :

```java
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MessageBodyReaderJSON implements MessageBodyReader<APojo> {

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public APojo readFrom(Class<APojo> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException {

    APojo p = new ObjectMapper().readValue(entityStream, APojo.class);

    return p;
    }
}
```

But when I start my web server the following excpetion is thrown:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: 
Method, public my.package.TestViewRestController.getPojo( java.lang.String, my.package.APojo, java.lang.String), 
annotated with GET of resource, class my.package.TestViewRestController, 
is not recognized as valid Java method annotated with @HttpMethod.
```

When I replace the APojo parameter by a String it works. It seems the provider is ignored.

With the last version of Jersey I don't get the issue (I didn't have also to declare providers) but I cannot upgrade because the app needs to run on Java 5 (and the last jersey runs only from Java 6).

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use structured POJOs with query parameters, just simple scalar values? Structured values are usually sent as PUT/POST payload (in JSON or XML).

Comment: I managed to do it with jersey **1.16** and jackson with the  servlet init-param `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` to true. The mapping is done automatically. But the last version of jersey running on jdk5 is jersey **1.2** which is not doing that automatic mapping.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how the mapping is done -- I guess one can just parse JSON, and URL encoding can handle curly braces etc. So there's just the size limitation, which might be ok for small documents.